# What is the mass of an AT-TE?

Tags: star-wars

The [Wookieepedia Page](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/All_Terrain_Tactical_Enforcer) about the AT-TE does apparently not contain info on its mass/weight (presuming a gravity like on Earth).

Is a canonical source on this available? If yes: Which?, if no: How much would the mass of (something like) an AT-TE propably be (approximately)?

Comment: The Tank Mark VIII, which has comparable dimensions (it's a bit smaller), weighs 38 tons. Obviously, the technology is vastly different - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tank_Mark_VIII.

Comment: Strictly speaking it depends which world it's on at the time!

Comment: I imagine that for stability, the lower legs and "feet" would have to be made of heavier alloys than the "body", which would have to be made of fairly light, tough alloys.

Comment: Best ask for mass/displacement, not weight.

Comment: It weighs less than 12 parsecs.

Comment: @Liath actually the mass would not change depending on the planet, that is the nice thing about mass. 1 cc of water will still have a mass of 1g but the _weight_ of it will change depending on the current planet.

Comment: @DarthSatan it couldn't weigh parsecs at all because a parsec is a measurement of length equal to about 3.26 light-years. It would be like saying, my sandwich weighs less than 5 km.

Comment: Joke. Head. Over.

Comment: @Cyberson the question has been. Updated, at the time if commenting it was about weight

Comment: @SSumner Nothing goes over my head. My reflexes are too fast, I would catch it.

Comment: Would answers from books be accepted at this point?

Comment: @Virusboy - I don't whether or not that's what the OP was looking for specifically, but since it is one answer from an (semi) authoritative source, I would say it is a good answer...provided, of course, that you can source it

Comment: Mass, unlike weight, is independent of gravity. I.e. an objects mass on the Moon is the same as its mass on the surface of the Earth.

Answer (score 10):

For vehicles an important consideration is its [ground pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_pressure), how much force per area (psi or kPa) is being exerted on the ground.  The ground can only support so much before the vehicle sinks into the mud.  If we can calculate the area of the AT-TE's feet, this can be used to establish an upper limit on the vehicle's mass.

Ground pressure is *weight* over area.  Normally this would be a problem for a space-fairing army as different planets would have different gravities producing different weights (and thus ground pressures) for the same vehicle.  A vehicle that worked on the Moon would sink into the ground on the Earth.  Fortunately for us, [most inhabited bodies in Star Wars have Earth-like gravity](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Gravity).  If there's evidence of the AT-TE performing well on high gravity worlds, the mass estimate would be lower.

The AT-TE's feet are a problem.  Tracks greatly reduce ground pressure by having a large area relative to the size of the vehicle.  An M1 tank has half the ground pressure of a family car despite being 40 times the mass.  The AT-TE doesn't have tracks, it has feet.  More area than wheels, not as much as tracks.

To make matters worse, the M1A1's ground pressure is fairly constant whether it's moving or standing still.  [The AT-TE walks (inefficiently) by moving three feet off the ground at a time](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fy9X3_PWI60#t=0m21s).  All its weight must be supported by its remaining three feet halving its ground area.

What's the area of those feet?  [Wookieepedia states an AT-TE is 13.2 meters long](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/All_Terrain_Tactical_Enforcer).  To figure this out I scaled up [a picture of an AT-TE](https://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20090425021909/starwars/images/5/5e/AT-TE_TCW.jpg) so that the vehicle is 13 cm long giving a 1 cm = 1 m measurement.  I then measured the feet to be 1.5 cm wide giving a diameter of 1.5 meters and a radius of 0.75 meters.  I will assume they are circular.  Area of a circle is `pi * radius * radius` which gives us `3.14 * 0.75 m * 0.75 m` and an area of 1.75 sq meters.

Each foot also has four [duckbills](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grouser) to increase their effective area.  They're a bit harder to measure because of the perspective, I will approximate them as a 0.5m x 0.25m rectangular area giving 0.125 sq meters per duckbill.

So each foot, plus four duckbills, has an approximate area of 2.25 sq meters.  Three feet on the ground while walking us 6.75 sq meters of ground area while walking.

I'll use the simple formula for static ground pressure, weight / area.  When walking the AT-TE would exert even more.  [An M1A1 tank has a ground pressure of 103 kPa](https://www.globalsecurity.org/military/systems/ground/m1-specs.htm), excellent off-road performance and a top speed comparable to the AT-TE's 60 kph.  103 kPa is 10,300 kg per sq meter.  With 6.75 sq meters to work with we get about 70 metric tons or a bit more than an M1A1 tank.

An adult horse exerts 170 kPa.  While this might seem a better analogy to an AT-TE than a tank, they both have legs, a horse and an AT-TE move very differently.  But why not, let's use a horse as our upper bound.  170 kPa is about 17,000 kg per sq meter.  Since we have 6.75 sq meters to work with, we get an upper bound weight for the AT-TE of 114,750 kg or about 114 metric tons.

Let's run [Null's "scaled up M1A1" estimate](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/66191/1441) through the formula.  284,489 kg / 6.75 sq meters is about 42,000 kg per sq meter or 420 kPa.  This is roughly the ground pressure for a bicycle which have awful off road performance (ever ride a bike on a beach?).  We can state with confidence this estimate is too high.  For its volume, the AT-TE must be lighter than a modern tank.

I would say an AT-TE weighs *at most* 110 metric tons and probably 70 metric tons given its demonstrated off road performance.

PS Somebody check my math. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a canonical source for the mass, but you can calculate an approximation.

One way would be to look up the dimensions and mass of a modern tank (such as the M1A1 Abrams) and scale it up to the size of the AT-TE. The [M1A1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M1A1_Abrams) has dimensions 7.93 x 3.66 x 2.44 (not including the gun, which increases the length) for a total volume of 70.82 m^3 and weighs 63 tons. On Earth [a ton equals 907.18474 kg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_ton) so its mass is 57,152 kg.

Using the dimensions provided on the AT-TE's Wookieepedia page as 13.2 x 5.32 x 5.02 meters, its volume is 352.52 m^3, which is 4.98 times the volume of the M1A1. Assuming the M1A1 and AT-TE have comparable average density, the AT-TE's mass is 4.98 times the mass of the M1A1, or 284,489 kg.

Comment: This brings it into the range of a fully loaded Haul Truck - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haul_truck. This seems like a reasonable estimation - much higher, and it wouldn't be effective for combat operations - it would simply claw up the environment and not be able to move.

Comment: I see a lot of unfounded assumptions here. The M1A1 is designed to protect soldiers from vastly different weapons than the AT-TE.

Comment: How do you know the humanoid's physical size in Star Wars is similar to (real) Humans? Maybe they're all a micro meter of our SI-unit meters (note that it is nowhere stated that an [Imperial Standard Meter](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Imperial_standard_meter) corresponds to a real-world meter). Consequently, we cannot approximate the weight of the tanks, nor can we infer the gravity constants of the planets they run around on.

Comment: @bitmask - assuming the laws of physics are the same, a rocky body must be at least approx 600km diameter to form a sphere under it's own gravity.  Since the planets of Star Wars are spheres and since we can see in the movies that they have horizons, that puts something of a constraint on the size range (somebody else can calculate it...)

Comment: @bitmask I did make some assumptions in my calculation. It's possible (and quite probable) that the distance scales are different and that the armor is different due to a difference in weapons. However, I think my assumptions are at least partly justified due to the fact that [fine-tuning of the universe for life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-tuned_Universe) puts constraints on the laws of physics in the Star Wars universe. Moreover, I think it is useful to assume they are comparable so that we can imagine what an AT-TE would look like in our universe.

Comment: Using an M1A1 isn't bad for an order of magnitude guess, but most of their weight is in their armor and weapons.  The differences in material science alone would throw off the calculations between armored machines of the 21st century and Star Wars.