# How do AT-TE Walkers climb vertical cliffs?

Tags: star-wars

In *Star Wars: The Clone Wars* TV series, AT-TE Walkers were able to climb vertical walls like lizards (Battle of Teth). You can also see it in *Star Wars: The Clone Wars* video game.

What mechanism in their legs facilitates this vertical climbing? Vacuum, mechanical drill grips or something else?

Comment: Definitely non-canon, but DARPA has been doing research on how gecko's grip surfaces, apparently they do it by utilising inter-molecular forces. http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/how-geckos-get-a-grip/

Comment: @Jaydee Such Inter-molecular forces can barely support heavy things against gravity.

Comment: Really? http://gizmodo.com/darpas-gecko-inspired-gloves-let-anyone-climb-up-flat-w-1587159519 That's almost 260 pounds on two climbing paddles on a 25 ft glass wall.

Comment: @Jaydee Look at the last paragraph of that article. Weight does matter. The tech can support you, but not AT-TE.

Comment: At the moment, but with centuries of research...

Comment: @Jaydee No, there's a limitation from underlying physics of materials. Unless one can change the property of molecule, it's impossible.

Comment: You were asking about possible mechanisms for a fantasy vehicle to climb vertical walls. A modified development of the gecko's foot idea that depends on inter-atomic or inter-subatomic forces would easily be able to support the weight of a large vehicle or even many of them.

Comment: They called walkers, not climbers. Now you wonder if they are any Imperial Climbers. :))

Comment: For a universe that has artificial gravity as a standard technology, walking on walls is a simple task.

Comment: @BBlake They do tumble down under the influence of nature Gravity. So, no, artificial gravity isn't used.

Comment: But usually only when they've been damaged, which could take the gravity controls offline.  At least that is how it appears from that shown in the Clone Wars movie/series.

Comment: @BBlake Can artificial gravity tech generate gravity outside the vessel? If yes, why would one need rocket thrusters in ships? Just freely fall towards a direction... Certainly, artificial gravity isn't used in AT-TE climbing.

Comment: @Jaydee Based on test results in 2012 http://www.darpa.mil/Our_Work/DSO/Programs/Z_Man.aspx A 16 in^2 sheet of that material supported 660 pounds. Based on the area of the AT-TE feet from answers to http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/66096/what-is-the-mass-of-an-at-te then we have 1.75 sq meters per foot, which if covered in the stuff would support 111870 lbs, or 50 metric tons. At least 3 feet of the AT-TE on the wall would mean 150 metric tons of support, which is less weight than the best answer for the afore mentioned question states. So in Earth like gravity, geckskin would work.

Comment: @SFruggiero You calculated like it's a linear relationship... which is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Only some models of the [AT-TE walker](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/All_Terrain_Tactical_Enforcer) were even capable of scaling vertical cliffs, similar to the later [UT-AT transport](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Unstable_Terrain_Artillery_Transport).

> Some of the AT-TE had the ability to reverse their repulsion, causing
>   gription fields and allowing the vehicle to ascend sheer surfaces if
>   needed. [source](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Unstable_Terrain_Artillery_Transport)

Comment: What do you mean by reversing repulsion and griping field? What's your canon source of second paragraph?

Comment: The AT-TE uses similar technologie wich was improve with the UT-AT transport. All of this tech is explained in the UT-AT link ;) ... and to be honest I'm not a scientist nor a technobable expert so I dont really know what THEY mean by "reversing repulsion and griping field"

Comment: Man, UT-AT is like a bug.. :D

Comment: @SachinShekhar Yes lol they are awesome

Comment: I just read the source.. Sorry, answer is wrong. UT-AT were equipped with 16 low-power repulsorlift (anti-gravity tech) instead of legs. For leg-based guys, your quoted theory isn't applicable.

Comment: @SachinShekhar Yes cause *SOME* of the AT-TE legs were equipped with repulsorlift as well. the vehicule was to heavy and they decided to improve this tech with the UT-AT but it was still to heavy and that limited the speed

Comment: `SOME of the AT-TE legs were equipped with repulsorlift as well` ~> Source?

Comment: There is no source but my 1st paragraph wich is practicly a Quotes from the AT-TE page still stand wich states " AT-TE walker were even capable of scaling vertical cliffs, similar to the later UT-AT transport." wich mean it was not grips or grapling device or anything else. it was *similar* and that was later improved

Comment: lol comment was to long It might not have been *repulsorlift* but it was something similar that had to do with the repulsor and the gription field